# Way to send net messages to a set of users under Windows server 2003

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003

Is there a way to send net messages to a set of users in the domain.

Suppose the domain contains 100 machines and I need to send net messages to 10 of them. Is this possible in Windows Server 2003.

***Edit:***

I know how to send a message to a single machine. I would like to know whether it could be possible to send a message to more than 1 user using a single net send command.

Answer (score 4):

You really want an instant messaging client on those comptuers to do what you're trying to do in lieu of the "Messenger Service". AFAIK, the "Messenger Service" is considered deprecated by Microsoft.

That having been said, if you *have* to do this, use the syntax below to send messages to specific users with the "NET SEND" command:

```
NET SEND <username> "Message"
```

The only way to send a message to multiple computers at a time is through either the "NET SEND /USERS", "NET SEND *", or "NET SEND /DOMAIN:domainname" arguments. There is no other mechanism.

If you had your list of users in a text file, you could do something like the following from a command-prompt:

```
FOR /F %i IN (userfile.txt) DO NET SEND %i "Message here"
```

Comment: Please see my edit

Comment: +1 but it's probably also worthwhile mentioning that the Messenger service is disabled by default in all recent (and some not-so-recent) versions of Windows.  Enable at your own risk, and be aware of the consequences of doing so.

Answer (score 1):

To send to specific users? You could use the "msg.exe" program in Windows Server 2003.

However, you'll need to script it if you want it to talk to multiple computers.

Answer (score 0):

Like this, however, as mentioned previously, the Messenger service is disabled by default and can be abused (all known vulnerabilities have been patched, so it's more of a social engineering / silly pranks issue such as obscene messages "anonymously" being sent to a particular person):

```
net send /domain:<domain> <message>
```

Documentation: [Net send command](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/net_send.mspx?mfr=true)

Answer (score 0):

NET SEND IP adress "Message"

Answer (score 0):

Use a third party LAN messenger maybe a good choice to replace net send command.
Check out the comparison between [net send vs LAN messenger](http://www.bigantsoft.com/net_send.html).